# Making sure my form isn't being submitted multiple times with jquery show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

So when someone hits Reply, I am attempting to pop-up a form to type your response.  Once the form is submitted, it disappears until the next time you hit Reply.

This is working except after the 1st time, I am submitting the information twice.  If I do it a third time, the form submits three times.  Essentially what is happening is the previous form doesn't seem to be resetting after I hide it again.

I checked this website/google and have tried using reset() but it didn't work.  Below is the code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.secretfeed button', function () {
    var message_id = $(this).attr('name');

    $(".comment_box").show();

    $("#m_id").val(message_id);
    var value = document.getElementById("m_id").value;

    $('#comment_form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var commentData = $(this).serialize();
        $.post('../../process_comment.php', commentData, processData);

        function processData(data) {
            //$('comment_form').reset()
            $(".comment_box").hide();
            $('#comment_form')[0].reset();

            RefreshFeed();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than initializing the submit function on every click, move it outside the click function. jQuery may be creating an instance of it for each click.

```
$('#comment_form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var commentData = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('../../process_comment.php', commentData, processData);

    function processData(data) {
        //$('comment_form').reset()
        $(".comment_box").hide();
        $('#comment_form')[0].reset();

        RefreshFeed();
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '.secretfeed button', function () {
    var message_id = $(this).attr('name');

    $(".comment_box").show();

    $("#m_id").val(message_id);
    var value = $("#m_id").val();
});
```

The alternative is to unbind the click function before reusing it.

Answer (score 0):

We want a reusable way to handle the state. We will save the state of the button in a boolean which gets turned on and off depending on the status of the request. The pattern is the following:

```
var isSending = false;

function onSubmit() {
  isSending = true;
  // Send data
}

function onComplete() {
  // done sending data
  isSending = false;
}

if (!isSending) {
  onSubmit();
}

// When data sending is finished:
onComplete();
```

The above can be encapsulated in a more functional way that uses promises to manage the state. (jQuery AJAX functions all return a promise-like object):

```
function oneAtATimeFunction(promisedFunction) {
  var pendingPromise;
  function reset() { pendingPromise = null; }
  return function() {
    if (pendingPromise) { return pendingPromise; }
    pendingPromise = promisedFunction.apply(promisedFunction, arguments)
      .always(reset);
    return pendingPromise;
  }
}

function submitForm() {
  return $.ajax({
    url:    '/foo',
    method: 'POST',
    data:   { data: 'from form' }
  });
}

$('#submit-button').on('click', oneAtATimeFunction(submitForm));
```

Adding a little flare to the UI We can add a way to turn on and off the submit button. First we will define a helper function to handle the on and off state:

```
function buttonEnable(enabled) {
  $('#submit-button').attr('disabled', !enabled);
}

buttonEnable(false); // disable the button
buttonEnable(true);  // enable the button
```

Putting it all together:

```
function onClick() {
  buttonEnable(false);
  return onSubmit()
    .always($.proxy(buttonEnable, null, true));
    // The above is also the same as:
    // .always(function() { buttonEnable(true); });
}

$('#submit-button').on('click', oneAtATimeFunction(onClick));
```

To see this in action here is a [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/yufuki/3/edit).